# Counting $K_4$'s in a Paley Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-fields, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ be prime, and let $G$ be a graph such that $|V(G)| = p$ and $\{u,v\} \in E(G) \Longleftrightarrow u-v \equiv x^2 \pmod{p}$ for some integer $x$.

**How many times does $G$ contain $K_4$ as a subgraph?**

---

Alternatively, one can ask for the number of subsets $S = \{u_1,\ldots,u_4\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $u_i - u_j$ is a quadratic residue for $i,j \in \{1,\ldots,4\}$, $i \neq j$.

Comment: Is the number of triangles obvious?

Comment: I don't know whether this will help or not but, if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ then $\exists$ integers $a,b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = p$

Comment: $S$ yields a copy of $K_4$ if and only if the translated $S+t$ does. Therefore w.l.o.g. $u_1=0$ (we do need to be careful not to overcount though). Assuming that, then all of $u_2,u_3,u_4$ need to be squares. If $a\in\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ then $S$ yields a $K_4$ if and only if $a^2S$ does. Therefore we can further reduce to the case $u_2=1$. That leaves the enumeration of $K_4$s coming from $\{0,1,u_3,u_4\}$ (and accentuates the need to be careful not to overcount). Not sure how much this helps, if at all.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is indeed the way to start.  You look at the neighborhood of $0$, which includes all the quadratic residues, then within that graph you look at the neighborhood of $1$.  Unfortunately there is still a lot of work to do at this point.  I have included a link to the result, but I think it is too long to summarize as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to do this, or are you just curious? This paper has a formula, but summarizing the argument would be way to long for me to put here: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~revans/Pulham.pdf

Computational is nice too (computed in Magma):

p =  5 Number of K4 subgraphs:  0

p =  13 Number of K4 subgraphs:  0

p =  17 Number of K4 subgraphs:  0 *

p =  29 Number of K4 subgraphs:  203

p =  37 Number of K4 subgraphs:  555

p =  41 Number of K4 subgraphs:  1025

p =  53 Number of K4 subgraphs:  3445

p =  61 Number of K4 subgraphs:  6100

p =  73 Number of K4 subgraphs:  13140

p =  89 Number of K4 subgraphs:  31328

p =  97 Number of K4 subgraphs:  46560

[* It is worth noting that for $p=17$, the Paley graph is the largest graph $G$ for which neither $G$ nor $G^{C}$ contain a copy of $K4$.]

Comment: I saw this problem written on the board in our lounge several months ago and I got to thinking about it. I don't know much about its origins or connections beyond that, but I imagine I could easily do some digging.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised to learn that there is no very clean formula. Good job digging up a reference!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! I started trying to work through it by exploiting the strongly regular structure, but quickly realized that that didn't give enough information.  It is a cool problem though, I'm now feeling motivated to maybe work through the details of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Since Paley Graphs are quasi-random, the density of their sub graphs are asymptotically the same as those of the Erdős–Rényi model with the same edge density. QR3 on page 9 of [this](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/bookxx/hombook-almost.final.pdf) book by Lovász. For this case, Paley graphs have density 1/2, thus we can instead just think of ER graphs where p=1/2. If you look at any four vertices in an ER graph, the probability that they make a complete subgraph will be $p^6(1-p)^0$ since there must be 6 included edged and 0 excluded edges. There are $\binom{n}{4}$ choices of vertices, each with a $p^6$ probability of being a $K_4$, thus since $p=\frac{1}{2}$, you should expect around $\frac{1}{64}\binom{n}{4}$ $K_4$’s on average for large $n$.